# Function double in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this definition:

```
data AEB2 a = Nil | Un a | Conc (AEB2 a) (AEB2 a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and I have:

```
foldAEB2 :: b -> (a->b) -> (b->b->b) -> (AEB2 a) -> b
foldAEB2 fnil fsin fcon t = case t of
                                       Nil -> fnil
                                       Un s -> fsin s
                                       Conc u v -> fcon (rec u) (rec v)                                   
                                       where rec = foldAEB2 fnil fsin fcon
```

I need do one function "double" using foldAEB2. One example is

I need help doing this function. Thanks

Comment: What do those angle brackets mean?

Comment: Its an example, you must thinks only in a duplicate data

Comment: Your most recent edit changed the question completely. Perhaps you should leave the first problem, your solution to it, and ask what it has to do with the second problem.

Comment: I've rolled the question back to its original form. If you need help understanding why, you can ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Your most recent edit makes it impossible even to guess what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few hints

`foldAEB2 Nil Un Conc` is the identity function

`foldAEB2 Nil Un Conc :: AEB2 a -> AEB2 a`

```
Un                       :: a -> AEB2 a
\a -> Conc (Un a) (Un a) :: a -> AEB2 a
```

Comment: some more help please?

Comment: I think that between dfeuer's answer and mine we have already given you more help than we probably should.

Comment: @christianrusso, you're being made to wait before asking another question because this one attracted a lot of down votes. The way to fix that is to *improve* the question so people cancel their down votes or other people vote it up. Changing it to a completely different question makes the answers nonsense and attracts even more down votes by making people angry at you. Go back to the original question, add more information on what you need,

Comment: what your thoughts are, where you got stuck, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to write a function

```
double :: AEB2 a -> AEB2 a
double = foldAEB2 fnil fsin fcon
```

You can think of `foldAEB2` as replacing each `Nil` with `fnil`, each `Un` with `fsin` and each `Conc` with `fcon`. Can you draw a picture of the data structure before and after and figure out what what should replace each constructor?